# RHIPE rhput() does not work

Tags: r, hadoop

I'm using `Rhipe` based on `Hadoop` to do some data analytics, but seems `rhput()` function does not work.

```
library(Rhipe)
Loading required package: codetools
Loading required package: rJava
------------------------------------------------
| Please call rhinit() else RHIPE will not run |
------------------------------------------------

rhinit()
Rhipe: Using Rhipe.jar file
Initializing Rhipe v0.75.1
2015-10-14 19:07:38,429 WARN  [main][NativeCodeLoader] Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Initializing mapfile caches
rhput('/home/hadoop/downloads/user.txt','/RHIPE/input/')
```

Then, I found '/RHIPE/input/' is located under local root directory, instead of hdfs' directory:

```
system("ls /")
app  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  lib  lib64  lost+found  
media  mnt  opt  proc  RHIPE  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var  
vmlinuz
```

No '/RHIPE/input' under HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, HADOOP_CONF_DIR must be set to the directory where hadoop's core-site.xml and other *-site.xml files are located.